# How can I disable Phone, SMS, Market and 3G functionality from Android?

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-droid

I am trying to convert my old Motorola Droid (running CyanogenMod 7) into a device my kids can use without me worrying about them making phone calls or downloading apps I don't know of.  My needs are:

1. Disable / uninstall the ability to make phone calls
2. Disable / uninstall the ability to send text messages
3. Disable / uninstall cellular data connectivity (should only be able to work on wifi)
4. Password protect the Market

Is there a ROM out there that already has this, or some pointers on how I can do this myself on Cyanogen?

Answer (score 6):

Re: 1,2,3

Removing SIM card is the safest option, but you could try enabling modified airplane mode in the system settings : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html

in *adb shell* you could try :

```
su
sqlite3 data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
insert into system (name,value) values('airplane_mode_on',1);
insert into system (name,value) values('airplane_mode_radios','cell');
.exit
reboot
```

Re.4

Have you tried apps like https://market.android.com/details?id=com.vlobe.smartappcloud.android.parentalcontrol

You could also remove the Market app completely and only install apks via *adb*.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you simply remove the SIM module from that phone? Android can work well without SIM.

The only thing that you miss is the ability to protect the market (or any other apps) with a password. One of the following apps could help you achieve the desired result:

- [Protector](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.androidpassword.core)
- [Smart App Protector](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sp.protector.free)

Comment: The Motorla Droid (US version) is a CDMA2000 phone. It doesn't have a SIM card.

Answer (score 1):

You could flash an incorrect baseband into the phone.  It will knock out the phone radio part completely until a correct baseband is flashed.  At least this is true on my Verizon Droid (Sholes).